# Bathroom sink faucet handle is tight causing it to work off the nut holding to sink. Can the handle be fixed?

Tags: repair, faucet, bathroom-fixtures

You can see in the picture a faucet handle ( cold ) for a bathroom sink.  The handle/lever on top is very tight to turn, so when you move it it forces the base, which caused to work off the nut under the sink. 
Instead of replaceing the entire fixture, can this type of handle be taken apart and repaired?  I see no set screws, only what is in the picture.
I appreciate your help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps a new Stem or cartridge will not be as stiff ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an issue with the handle. You need to find our why **the valve that the handle turns** is so stiff. Often you can disassemble the valve and lube it up with plumber's grease to make them turn easier, other times it is not so simple; it depends on the valve and the problem.